# Why Pipeline Failed when there's test case failed

Tags: python, gitlab, robotframework, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

i'm running robotframework in Gitlab-CI.

the problem i'm facing is, if there's any test case failed on the run, it will failed the pipeline too. so how to prevent the pipeline to failed? because the test failed, not the entire build process.

for now, this is how i run the robotframework on `gitlab-ci.yml`

```
- robot --exitonfailure -i "android-test" --outputdir ./output Android/Androidtest.robot
```

for example, i have 3 test cases on Androidtest.robot Test Suite:

1. register

2. fillin_profile

3. checkout_order

if register case and fillin_profile passed, but checkout order failed, the Ci pipeline will failed. i don't want that to be failed, because on the next job is to send the robotframework test report to gdrive, and it will never sent if the pipeline failed.

is that because i add `--exitonfailure` parameter btw? how to solve this?

Comment: In your deployment concept what is the purpose of the tests? In most others they are there to prevent getting faulty code deployed.

Comment: yes, but i created the test job right after the build job on the same pipeline. is that the correct way?

Comment: `--exitonfailure` will stop test execution if any critical test fails. Should not be a problem. Without considering your overall setup, you possibly need the  `--nostatusrc` argument, which does the following "Sets the return code to zero regardless of failures in test cases. Error codes are returned normally."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace  `--exitonfailure` with `--nostatusrc`.

If there are test failures, robot will exit with exitcode other than 0. Gitlab and for that matter every ci ever, looks if any command it executes with exitcode other than 0 and thinks that there was a failure.  With `--nostatusrc` robot will always exit with 0 and thus your ci doesnt think there where failures.

Do consider that if you go with suppressing exit codes, you either loose the ability to mark the job within CI as failed if there was test failures unless you provide some other mechanism to do that if you happen to need such feature.

Comment: thanks, this suits my needs. i need to do some works after executing test (on the same job), and finally execute a script that reads the robotframework test result itself. if it has test case fail(s), the script will issue ```sys.exit(1)``` that will fail the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of CI is to fail when tests fail.
Uploading your test results or reports shouldn’t be an extra job in the pipeline. I don’t know about robotframework but GitLab supports publishing of artifacts after failed tests.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/junit_test_reports.html

Comment: ah i see. what i want to achieve is the testing job (pipeline) completed successfully (including report on which test case failed). is that the correct way?

Comment: yes, uploading the results shouldn't be an extra job if you expect to get them uploaded after a failure